# Can introductory phrase be followed by a question?

Tags: meaning, questions, commas

Can the introductory phrase "**Among thousands of search results,**" be followed by the question "**which one do you choose to click on**"?

> Among thousands of search results, which one do you choose to click on?

If not, how would construct a sentence conveying the same meaning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel it would be better phrased as:

> **From** the thousands of search results, which one **would** you choose to click on?

"Among" literally means "in the middle of" or "surrounded by". Although it is fairly clear in your sentence that you are asking the reader to choose from the search results they are "among", in other similarly-phrased sentences it would not be so clear.

For example:

> Among thousands of scam websites, which will you choose?

Here you are not asking someone to choose *from* the scam websites - you are asking them how they will choose a *genuine* one *from among* all the scams.

So in this instance where you are asking which a person would choose out of the given possibilities, it is better to begin with "*from the thousands...*", or alternatively "*of the thousands...*".